# getting undefined from JSON response

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

setting up for the *client* to *register*.
this is the function that registers a client.

```
  registerAsClient(){
  this.loading =this.loadingCtrl.create({
   content:"Setting up Account"
  });
this.loading.present();
this.buildClientData();
console.log(this.clientData);
this.auth.store('clients', this.clientData).subscribe((response)=>{

  this.clients = response.json();
```

this is to show the response from the server after registration to console.

```
  console.log("Client ID : " + this.clients['clientId']);
  console.log("Savings Account ID : " + this.clients['savingsAccountId']);

  localStorage.setItem('clientID', this.clients['clientId']);
  localStorage.setItem('officeID', this.clients['officeId']);
  localStorage.setItem('savingsAccountID', this.clients['savingsAccountId']);

  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.loading.dismissAll();
    this.toastrCtrl.messenger('Successfully Registered'); 
    localStorage.setItem('registered', 'true');
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
       },5000)
  },error=>{
    if(error.status === 403){
      this.loading.dismissAll();
      this.toastrCtrl.messenger("Phone number already exists. Please use another");
    }else
     this.loading.dismissAll();
     this.toastrCtrl.messenger('Service unavailable. Please try again later'); 
     console.log(error);
      // alert(JSON.stringify("Error is  :" + error));
})
}
```

this is the response from the console registering 
i am able to get the client id but the savings account id is showing as undefined.

```
Client ID : 104 
Savings Account ID : undefined
```

total `json` response when testing with the endpoints.

```
{
"id": 89,
"accountNo": "000000089",
 "status": {
"id": 300,
"code": "clientStatusType.active",
"value": "Active"
 },
 "subStatus": {
"active": false,
"mandatory": false
 },
"active": true,
"activationDate": [
  2018,
  8,
 13
 ],
 "firstname": "Albertina",
 "lastname": "Ben-Patterson",
 "displayName": "Albertina Ben-Patterson",
 "mobileNo": "0201234598",
 "gender": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 },
 "clientType": {
 "active": false,
 "mandatory": false
  },
  "clientClassification": {
"active": false,
"mandatory": false
 },
"isStaff": false,
 "officeId": 10,
 "officeName": "Greater Accra Region",
 "timeline": {
 "submittedOnDate": [
  2018,
  8,
  13
 ],
"submittedByUsername": "admin",
"submittedByFirstname": "App",
"submittedByLastname": "Administrator",
"activatedOnDate": [
  2018,
  8,
  13
],
"activatedByUsername": "admin",
"activatedByFirstname": "App",
"activatedByLastname": "Administrator"
},
"savingsAccountId": 8,
"groups": [],
"clientNonPersonDetails": {
 "constitution": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 },
  "mainBusinessLine": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 }
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the code. In the json it has `Id` with a little `d`. In the code it has `ID` which a capital `D`.

Comment: i'm assigning  the response savingsAccountId to localStorage with the name savingsAccountID as the variable name

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code in my local system, But I didn't find anything suspicious.
I guess you better check out the code spelling while retrieving **savingsAccountId**. *ID --> Id*?

```
localStorage.setItem('savingsAccountID', this.clients['savingsAccountId'])

localStorage.getItem('savingsAccountID');
```

Also, its always advisable to generate error messages from the backend will save you from a great mess in the future.

Comment: Okay..let me get home.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no attribute with key `clientId` in your `json` body it is `id` so I think you are trying to print/get data from another `json` body which contains `clientId` key and doesn't contain a key for `savingsAccountId`.